# Is it a double coincidence $\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{\log(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\log n} \approx\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, number-theory, summation

Is this a double co-incidence or is there a reason why
$$
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{\log n!}{n^3 \log n} 
= \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{\log (n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\log n} \approx \lim_{n \to  \infty}\frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n} = \frac{1}{e}
$$

This this could be a coincidence because the difference between the sum and the limit is $< 0.0000523$ which is not earth shatering-ly small lets say as in case of the famous $e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}$. However there is some similarity in the form of the sum and the limit so this could be a double co-incidence i.e. not just in value but also on the form of the expression. Or is there an explanation why?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question at all but another expression that's exactly equal to $1/e$ is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{e}$$
Which is obivious by the Maclaurin of $e^x$

Comment: @bob. One more coincidence, my friend !